# Javascript framework that uses annotations for routing

Tags: javascript, framework

I'm very familiar with Symfony framework for PHP and love it's way of defining routes based on annotations.

Now I'm developing a project that uses Dojo + Node.js. I use Node to define a Rest API, so I've used Express.js. But I miss a lot Symfony's way to annotate routes.

Someone knows any javascript framework that uses annotations to define routes or a way that I can use route annotation with Express.js ?